# For $x \in G$, prove $|f(x)|$ divides $k$ if $f$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ and $|x| = k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a suspicion my proof for this implication is incorrect, because it proves something stronger than what is called for. I'd be grateful to anyone who can either verify it or explain to me why it is wrong.

Proof:  Since $f$ is a homomorphism, we have $f(e) = e^{'}$. Therefore

$e{'} = f(e) = f(x^{k})= f(\underbrace{x\ast x \ast \cdots \ast x}_{k})= \underbrace{y\bullet y \bullet \cdots \bullet y}_{k} = y^{k}$

So the order of $y$ is also $k$. Clearly, $k$ divides itself, so $|f(x)|$ divides $k$.

Thanks!

Comment: You've written the correct proof up until the very last bit - the key is that $f(x^{k}) = f(x)^{k}$, as you note. However, $y^{k} = e'$ does not imply that $y$ has order $k$ - it implies that $y$ has order dividing $k$, as the problem requires.

Comment: Hi Alex -- Thanks very much for the comments!  Although I believe you, I don't understand why if $y^{k} = e^{'}$, we can't conclude the order of $y$  is $k$.  I thought that was the definition of order...? Help!

Comment: Ah.  Just reviewed the definition of order.  We must be certain that $k$ is the $smallest$ possible integer such that $y^{k} = e^{'}$ before concluding the order of $y$ is $k$.  I haven't shown that.

Comment: In fact, the order of $f(x)$ may be considerably less that the order of $x$, for example, suppose $f: G \to H$ is the homomorphism $f(g) = e_H$ for all $g \in G$. Then the order of $f(x)$ is $1$ no matter *what* the order of $x$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove that if $y^k=e$, then $|y|$ divides $k$. Equivalently, I will show that if $|y|$ does not divide $k$, then $y^k\neq e$, so suppose that $k=a|y|+b$ for some $0<b<|y|$. It is clear that the result is true if $a=0$ by definition of $|y|$. We also have 
$$y^k=y^{a|y|+b}=y^by^{a|y|}=y^b(y^{|y|})^a=y^be^a=y^b\neq e$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments!  Very clear and helpful.

Comment: @ScentlessApprentice No problem.